# post-hoc analysis for interaction terms in logistic regression: emtrends(), type I error

Tags: r, logistic, interaction, lsmeans, type-i-and-ii-errors

I built a logistic regression, including the followed variables. And I tried to compare effects of temp among group and habitat using `emtrends()` in `emmeans` R package.

I have 3 questions about the followed results.

First, it feels like that there was type I error in the results. How can I figure out there is type I error or not?

Second, I wonder why df is Inf in my results of `emtrends()`.

Third, I ran `emtrends()` seperately for group variable and for habitat variable. My model included the interaction term between temp and habitat but not a habitat variable. Then, should I ran like this `emtrends(fit_1, ~habitat|group, var = "temp")`?

```
> str(dataset)
'data.frame':   1440 obs. of  6 variables:
$ habitat    : Factor w/ 4 levels "A","B","C",..: 2 2 3 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ group      : Factor w/ 4 levels "red","skyblue","indigo",..: 3 4 4 4 3 4 4 4 1 1 ...
$ temp       : num  15.5 13.9 13.9 15.4 15.5 ...
 $ event      : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ weight     : num  3 3 2.73 3 10 ...
 $ rain       : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...

> fit_1 <- glm(event ~ group*temp + rain + habitat:temp + rain:temp
               , weights = weight,family=binomial, data=dataset)

> summary(fit_1)

Call:
glm(formula = event ~ group * temp + rain + habitat:temp + 
 rain:temp, family = binomial, data = dataset, 
 weights = weight)

Deviance Residuals: 
 Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-3.6849  -1.7761  -1.1416  -0.2509   8.5246  

Coefficients:
                 Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)         -2.51354    0.63168  -3.979 6.92e-05 ***
groupskyblue         2.06381    0.85254   2.421  0.01549 *  
groupindigo          8.48504    0.97759   8.680  < 2e-16 ***
groupblack           4.09039    0.83798   4.881 1.05e-06 ***
temp                -0.06882    0.05273  -1.305  0.19187    
rain1                2.25311    0.89997   2.504  0.01230 *  
groupskyblue:temp   -0.24329    0.06062  -4.013 5.99e-05 ***
groupindigo:temp    -0.59809    0.06905  -8.662  < 2e-16 ***
groupblack:temp     -0.35243    0.06355  -5.546 2.92e-08 ***
temp:habitatB        0.20523    0.01928  10.644  < 2e-16 ***
temp:habitatC        0.20808    0.01925  10.807  < 2e-16 ***
temp:habitatD        0.17938    0.01955   9.173  < 2e-16 ***
temp:rain1          -0.17861    0.06167  -2.896  0.00378 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

 Null deviance: 9483.6  on 1439  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 8604.1  on 1427  degrees of freedom
AIC: 8630.1

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 6


> emt_fit_group <- emtrends(fit_1, ~group, var = "temp")
> summary(emt_fit_group)
group    temp.trend     SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
red          0.0903 0.0866 Inf   -0.0794    0.2601
skyblue     -0.2686 0.0719 Inf   -0.4096   -0.1276
indigo      -0.5297 0.0816 Inf   -0.6897   -0.3698
black       -0.2192 0.0803 Inf   -0.3765   -0.0619

Results are averaged over the levels of: rain, habitat 
Confidence level used: 0.95 

> emt_fit_habitat <- emtrends(fit_1, ~habitat, var = "temp")
> summary(emt_fit_habitat)
habitat  temp.trend     SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
A            -0.380 0.0547 Inf    -0.487   -0.2727
B            -0.175 0.0534 Inf    -0.279   -0.0701
C            -0.172 0.0534 Inf    -0.277   -0.0672
D            -0.201 0.0534 Inf    -0.305   -0.0960

Results are averaged over the levels of: group, rain 
Confidence level used: 0.95
```

Comment: In your third question, you ask about `emtrends(fit_1, ~alt|group, var = "temp")` but there is no variable named `alt` in the model -- so this is not a valid call. What variable did you mean `habitat` rather than `alt`?

Comment: @RussLenth Oh, I wrote it down wrong. The `alt` is corrected with `habitat`. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear why you think that there is "Type I error" (false positives) in your results. If the assumptions underlying the binomial model are correct, then you shouldn't be having false-positive results unless your model is overfitting the data. If you have more than 15 or so cases in the minority outcome class per coefficient that you are estimating (as you seem to), you are probably OK. You can check by repeating the modeling on multiple bootstrap samples.

For the degrees of freedom (`df`), the maximum-likelihood method used to fit the binomial logistic regression is based on asymptotic theory that holds in the limit of an *infinite* number of observations. Comparisons are then based on a normal distribution of coefficient estimates, the limit of the *t* distribution as the degrees of freedom approach infinity.

For your model, you are asking for trouble when you [omit the individual coefficient](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/11009/28500) for a predictor (`habitat`) that you are including in an interaction. You might get away with that if there's only 1 interaction term in the model, but you have several. I'd be reluctant to give advice on how to set up the `emtrends` in this situation.

Comment: Thank you! I decided to include a habitat variable in my model after reading the link you cited. And can you explain the method, repeating model anaysis on bootstrap samples, in detail?

Comment: @pineapple159 [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/373431/28500) outlines the process of the "optimism bootstrap," a good way to evaluate overfitting. Frank Harrell's notes on [Regression Modeling Strategies](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/) explain the bootstrap in Section 5.2 and show its use in model validation and calibration in Section 5.3.5. The `validate()` and `calibrate()` functions in Harrell's [`rms` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=rms) in R can do that for you if you use that package's `lrm()` function for logistic regression.