# What is the correct way to average random variables and get correct quantiles

Tags: probability, forecasting, random-variable, bootstrap

Say I have two random variables $A$ and $B$ which may or may not be independent. I also have their $0.95$ quantiles $Q95_A$ and $Q95_B$. What is a valid way to average these densities and obtain valid quantiles?

### Example Use Case

I am able to get draws from $A$ and $B$. In reality these random variables are probabilistic forecasting methods. I would like to obtain a combination forecast by averaging these densities.

### More Clairity - Is this a question about mixture densities or about convolution operations?

From the wikipedia page on mixture distributions https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution there is a distinction between when one would desire a mixture distribution vs a convolution operation.

**Mixture densities** are used when the the random variable's *density* is the sum of components

**Convolution operators** are used when the random variable's *value* is the sum of the underlying random variable values.

An example is given on the wikipedia page

> As an example, the sum of two jointly normally distributed random variables, each with different means, will still have a normal distribution. On the other hand, a mixture density created as a mixture of two normal distributions with different means will have two peaks provided that the two means are far enough apart, showing that this distribution is radically different from a normal distribution.

The goal here is convolution not a mixture density.

Answer (score 3):

The most flexible method I am aware of is to use the **bootstrap** approach. I have seen some recommend concatenation as a way to average densities [see this link](https://www.circonus.com/2018/11/the-problem-with-percentiles-aggregation-brings-aggravation/), but from my simulations I do not see that method working.

I will compare the *concatenation* (`concat`) approach and the *bootstrap* (`boot_avg`) approach here via simulation. My hope is that if there are other methods available they can also be run in a similar simulation.

#### Some math

To have a flexible method in hand which could work in general it is nice to start with an analytical solution and see which methods approach the analytical truth.

If random variable A is:

$$
f_A(x) = \int_{y=\infty}^{x} N(y\mid 10, 5) \, dy
$$

and random variable B is:

$$
f_B(x) = \int_{y=\infty}^{x} N(y\mid 20, 5) \, dy
$$

where

$$
N(x\mid\mu,\sigma) = \frac{e^{-\frac{1}{2}(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma})^2}}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}}
$$

Then the analytical solution would be:

$$
f_Z(x) = \int_{y=\infty}^{x} N(y\mid 15,\frac{5}{\sqrt{2}}) \, dy
$$

Conclusion, with $Z$ in hand, the true density of the average of two normals, we can now see which methods approach this density.

In the simulations below I show a bootstrap approach which seems to work well to average the densities and the quantiles generated from this method give valid quantiles which match the true $Z$.

#### Simulation

```py
from numpy.lib.function_base import meshgrid
import numpy as np
from itertools import product, repeat
from numpy.random import triangular, normal
from plotnine import ggplot, aes, facet_wrap, geom_histogram, stat_ecdf, labs
from plotnine.themes import theme_538
from plotnine.scales import scale_fill_manual, scale_color_manual
import pandas as pd

rng = np.random.default_rng(42)

red = "#DD0031"
white = "#FFFFFF"
burgandy = "#AF272F"
dark_blue = "#004F71"
light_blue = "#3EB1C8"
blackish = "#202336"

n, u1, u2, sd = 500, 10, 20, 5
u_avg = np.mean([u1,u2])
a = rng.normal(u1, sd, size=n)
b = rng.normal(u2, sd, size=n)
concat = rng.choice(np.concatenate([a,b]), size = n)
z = rng.normal(u_avg, sd/np.sqrt(2), size=n)
def boot(tuple_a_and_b):
  return np.mean([rng.choice(tuple_a_and_b[0]), rng.choice(tuple_a_and_b[1])])
tuple_a_and_b = (a,b)
boot_replications = repeat(tuple_a_and_b, n) # n replications
boot_avg = np.array(list(map(boot, boot_replications)))

df_distributions = pd.DataFrame({'A': a, 'B': b, 'boot_avg': boot_avg, 'concat': concat, 'true': z}).unstack().reset_index().rename(columns={"level_0": "distribution", 0: "value"}).drop(columns = "level_1")
df_distributions

(ggplot(df_distributions)
 + geom_histogram(aes(x = 'value', fill = 'distribution'), color = 'white')
 +facet_wrap('~distribution',ncol = 1)
 +theme_538()
 +scale_fill_manual(values = [red, burgandy, light_blue, dark_blue, blackish])
  +labs(title = "The Bootstrap Average Approaches The True Average")
)
```

[image]

```py
(ggplot(df_distributions)
 + stat_ecdf(aes(x = 'value', color = 'distribution'))
 +theme_538()
 +scale_color_manual(values = [red, burgandy, light_blue, dark_blue, blackish])
 +labs(title = "The Bootstrap Average Approaches The True Average")
)
```

[image]

Now lets see the $0.95$ quantile from the different distributions.

```py
data = {
  'calculation':['quantile(a, 0.95)','quantile(b, 0.95)','quantile(concat, 0.95)','quantile(boot_avg, 0.95)','mean(q95(a), q95(b))','true'],
  'q95': [  
  np.round(np.quantile(a, .95), 2),
  np.round(np.quantile(b, .95), 2),
  np.round(np.quantile(concat, .95), 2),
  np.round(np.quantile(boot_avg, .95), 2),
  np.round(np.mean([np.quantile(a, .95),np.quantile(b, .95)]), 2),
  np.round(np.quantile(true, .95), 2)
  ]
}
pd.DataFrame(data).to_markdown(index=False)
```

| calculation | q95 |
| --- | --- |
| quantile(a, 0.95) | 18.02 |
| quantile(b, 0.95) | 28.09 |
| quantile(concat, 0.95) | 26.68 |
| quantile(boot_avg, 0.95) | **20.9** |
| mean(q95(a), q95(b)) | 23.06 |
| true | **20.58** |

The the plots and table show that the concatenation method does not approach the true average density while the bootstrap approach does.

Comment: Nice code, but I'm puzzled:
if you have say 100 samples from $A$ and 100 from $B$,
then you have 200 samples of $A \cup B$ together.
Can't you just sort the 200, and read off whatever quantiles you want ?
Could you describe the real problem ?

Comment: I think AUB would be a 50:50 mixture not a convolution?

Comment: why one or the other -- don't you just have 200 data points ?

Comment: @Alex do you have a reference for the bootstrap method? I'm interested on what is the procedure if the sample sizes are not the same, or if there are more than two variables.

Comment: @J.R.C. I do not. I looked in a number of my stats books and could not find much. I think this is because the problem may be more probability than stats. In my two probability texts the most I was able to get was the difference between mixtures and convolutions, but not a lot of code or simulations on implementing arithmetic in both cases. I learned that mixtures are the easier of the two because you just decide what proportion you want from each distribution. Convolutions are something that seem a little more complicated so I just tested the bootstrap here.

Comment: @denis what you are describing is the `concat` method which I showed above is not sufficient.

Comment: @Alex I was wondering if the following would be reasonable to extend it to $M$ variables with $n_i$ samples each, $i=1,...,M$:

a) Define $N = \sum_i n_i$

b) draw $M$ samples $c_j, j=1,...,M$ from a multinomial distribution with probabilities $p_i = n_i/N$

c) pick a random sample for each variable $c_j$ and take their mean

d) repeat... $N$ times? this is where I have more doubts, it doesn't need to be $N$, it could be something like the mean of all the $n_i$.

(Sorry, I'm failing to add line breaks here)

Comment: What happens with a heavy-tailed distribution instead of normal ? Also, [using-bootstrap-to-obtain-sampling-distribution-of-1st-percentile](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/119748/using-bootstrap-to-obtain-sampling-distribution-of-1st-percentile) discusses bias confidence intervals for the quantile estimeates.

Comment: @denis If the bootstrap is having difficulty estimating the 1st percentile then I would generate more random samples for A and B. In my set up I have ways of generating as many numbers as I want from A and B. It is just that A and B do not come from named distributions.